# why the author used the word have + ing in this context?

Tags: syntax

Kaba Gandhi married four times in succession, ***having*** lost his wife each time by death.

Comment: Unless *in succession* is explicitly modified as, for example, *in **rapid** succession*, this usage strikes me as very "strange". It's like saying *He sneezed three times, **one after the other***. How else could you marry or sneeze multiple times? They're not the kind of activities you can do several of simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

having lost- perfect participle

Kaba Gandhi... , **having lost**...

We can also say Kaba Gandhi... , **losing**...

There are two sentences- 'Kaba Gandhi lost...' and 'He married...'

Now let's join two sentences using perfect participle or present participle.

Having lost...Kaba Gandhi married... or Kaba Gandhi married...having lost...(perfect participle)

Losing...Kaba Gandhi married...or Kaba Gandhi married...losing...(present participle)

perfect participle- having + past participle

present participle- verb + ing